Local env. communication between two dockerized API Platform apps
I have to repos, both of them having two API Platform based apps:
Now, both of them are dockerized with the default Docker configuration that API Platform is shipping. I have the following scenario:

App1, inside its own container (C1) needs to send a request to App2 that lives inside its own container (C2).

I've managed to crate a bridge between them, that looks similar to this (following this article: https://medium.com/@murilolivorato/connecting-two-laravel-projects-built-in-two-docker-compose-environments-1a979e64f332):
compose.yaml (App1) inside C1:
services:
  php:
    [...]
    networks:
      - app1_network
      - app2_app1_network
  networks:
    app2_app1_network:
      external: true
    app1_network:

compose.yaml (App2) inside C2:
services:
  php:
    [...]
    networks:
      - app2_network
      - app1_network
  networks:
    app1_network:
      driver: bridge
    app2_network:

Now, these configurations seems to work. I can configure App1 to send a request to "https://<app2-container-name/api/v1/".
But the next bump I've hit is realted to HTTPS.
API Platform framework is exposing all endpoints (even locally), over HTTPS. And when I try to send a request from C1 to C2, using the configuration above, I hit the following error:
OpenSSL/3.0.13: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error for "https://<app-2-container-name>/api/v1/<some-endpoint>".
I'm kinda stuck at this point.

Does anyone have any idea how can I fix this? I'm not too versed into dev-ops stuff and I haven't played too much with HTTPS issues.
Does anyone knows how to disable HTTPS on local environment, for API Platform? I cannot seem to find out how in the framework documentation.

Initially I've tried to enable communication between C1 and C2, following the specified article. But after doing that, I get the OpenSSL/3.0.13: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error for "https://<app-2-container-name>/api/v1/<some-endpoint".
I've also tried to disable HTTPS in API Platform, on my local environment, but with no luck. Each request to HTTP, is redirected somewhere to HTTPS.

did you try setting API_PLATFORM_FORCE_HTTPS to false in ur docker yml file?

Hi @Qasim! No, to be honest, but can you reference where in the API Platform documentation is this variable API_PLATFORM_FORCE_HTTPS mentioned at? I cannot seem to find any reference of it anywhere. ‍♂️ I've tried adding it now, but with no resolution.
